# Can cooja connect to mosquitto server in ubuntu?

Tags: c, mqtt, mosquitto, contiki

I am new to contiki os and i am trying out mqtt in contiki os. But i had problem connecting my mote in cooja simulator to my mosquitto server on my ubuntu desktop. So is it possible to do that? I am trying to use IPv4 for this and my example for mqtt come from https://github.com/esar/contiki-mqtt

Thank you

Comment: You can use `tunslip` to create an IP tunnel between the root node in the sensor network and your PC over the serial port (serial comms are exported by Cooja).

Comment: @kfx thanks for the reply. To do this i need use border-router.c and udp-server.c to create the tunnel?

Comment: All `udp-server.c` examples are for IPv6. If you do not need IPv4, you should not specify that in your question.

Comment: thanks kfx. I was thinking if i could change it to work with IPv4 which originally its was using IPv6. But as Felipe Lavratti said it does not work with IPv4 so i change the code back to IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You need a RPL border router node with SLIP (Serial Line IP) enabled (I have never simulated physical Ethernet port in a node on Cooja).

In your RPL border router, open the "Serial Socket (Server)" and in the Linux console, run `tunslip6` to connect the RPL tree into your local network.

This is a tutorial: http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/RPL_Border_Router

After the tunslip6 is running, there's no difference from running the nodes physically, it's the same setup.

Now your nodes will be able to find your mosquitto server in the static IPv6 address you've configured. I remember to be using "aaaa::1". To be sure the network is up, ping6 your RPL border router.

ps: If it is a production application, you might not want to use MQTT. Nor TCP or packet segmentation scale well in the RPL, also MQTT can have fat payloads. Go UDP with CoAP or MQTT-SN.

Comment: hi Felipe Lavratti. my mosquitto server is running on my ubuntu desktop. So the ip address i should used for my mote to connect to server is ip address of my ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Felipe, he does mention that he's using IPv4. I suspect the procedure is very similar, but have only tried with IPv6 myself.

Comment: Agree about CoAP being better than MQTT for these networks.

Comment: Ipv4 won't route. RPL only uses ipv6. Tunslip6 creates a virtual network interface and set a local ip using command line options. That's the ip your nodes should look for. Follow the tutorial in the link.

Comment: Hi i had tried what your said  but i keep entering process_is_running method(in mqtt-service's mqtt_connect method) could your tell me what is it for? Sorry aboutt this i am not sure what its does. Is it for checking if the process is running? because if that the case why return -1?